# WPF: multi-column listbox / listview?

Tags: wpf, list, listview

I'd like to create a list in WPF that displays data in several columns, like Explorer display a list of files in 'Small icons' view mode:

[image: Multi-column list box]

Each item must be represented by a `DataTemplate` and the scrolling is supposed to be horizontal. How do I make such a list?

Comment: did you already check itemscontrol and itemscontrol.ItemsPanelTemplate for scrolling horizontal

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that, but couldn't find a way to make items stack up in multiple vertical columns.

Comment: uniformgrid or wrappanel can do this

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to change `ItemsPanel` of your `ListBox` to `WrapPanel` with vertical `Orientation` and disable vertical scroll bar on your `ListBox`
Something like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding=MyItems}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <!--my item template-->
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: great implementation - @JSJ's is nice as well but this is nice to have without the grid headers

Answer (score 11):

try something like below.

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

 <DataTemplate>
      <!--my item template-->
 </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

can use [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19395.multiple-columns-in-wpf-listbox.aspx) link

Answer (score 6):

try something like below.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                       ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                       MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

code behind sample.

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Files = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();
            var files = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\").GetFiles();
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                Files.Add(item);
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<FileInfo> Files { get; set; }
    }
```